# Swift. Setting contentInset of UIScrollView not working

Tags: uiscrollview, rx-swift

I have a UIView located a UIScrollView on it.

```
let curtainView = UIScrollView ()
curtainView.snp.makeConstraints {make in
            make.edges.equalToSuperview ()
}
```

And also UIView.

```
let someView = UIView ()
someView.snp.makeConstraints {make in
        make.top.equalToSuperview (). offset (10)
        make.leading.trailing.equalToSuperview (). inset (10)
}
```

Objective: Set contentInset for UIScrollView depending on UIView visibility. UIView's visibility changes through RxSwift.
I am doing the following

```
override func layoutSubviews () {
        super.layoutSubviews ()
        curtainView.contentInset.top = someView.isHidden? self.frame.minY: someView.frame.maxY
    }
```

The layoutSubviews method is called multiple times:

```
1.curtainView.contentInset.top == 0
2.curtainView.contentInset.top == 0
3.curtainView.contentInset.top == 30
```

However, visually the contentInset of someView remains unchanged. Only after the swipe does the curtain set the correct indents.
I do not have permission to add images, please see them on a third-party resource: https://youtu.be/LecHmLd9HP4

Comment: Use a UIStackView and your constraint change will happen automatically.

Comment: MY GOD. You are a genius. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Guys also do not forget to do setContentOffset

             let offset = CGPoint (x: .zero, y: bottomPositionLimit)
             setContentOffset (offset, animated: true)